Why do single-digit numbers go up to only 9? Why is 10 a two-digit number and cannot be written in a single-digit?
I've been studying the history of math, and I haven't figured out yet the answer to this question. I got an answer from someone else saying that we have needed to use unique symbols after 10. And, it would have been harder to perform arithmetic operations.
So, if you could give me your new explanations, and add to the current ones I got, that would be really helpful. Thanks!

Well, where do you stop?

The trade off for higher bases is: computations take less steps, but there is more overhead in memorizing the symbols and single digit arithmetic.

Because at the moment most humans use a base-10 numeral system. Computers use base 2. Maya used base 20. If humans had eight fingers, they would likely use base 8.

Are you asking why the Hindu-Arabic system uses base $10$ rather than another base?

$10$ represents numbers two, eight, ten and sixteen in bases two, eight, ten and sixteen respectively. If base sixteen was the highest in practice with it's alphabet containing $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f$, smaller bases will take their alphabet by picking up the required set starting from $0$ out of this. I am not a historian, but my guess is that decimal might have been the highest and most common base at some point.

Note that the word "digit" itself is itself indicative to the base-10 context: the Latin digitus means "finger or toe", of which we have 10 each on hands and feet respectively. (This does not explain why said counting scheme became most dominant. Another finger counting scheme is to count to 12 using finger knuckles, hence the prevalence of counting to 12 in some contexts. But this historical practice doesn't seem to have been combined with a positional number system like decimal was.)

We have 10 fingers because... some ancient sponge thought bilaterial symmetry was a good idea... and really that is all there is to it.  Sometimes there is no answer. Can't have an infinite number of symbols for every possible value so eventually we have to combine things.  Why'd we combine them the way we did? No reason, other cultures combined them in different ways. Roman numerals could have worked but the scalability of powers of bases has a distinct advantage as working with millions is the same as working with nano seconds. Why is the base 10? Why not? We've got ten fingers, don't we?

All the answers are good but it's not just that we have base 10.  It's how we deal with the bases that play.  Roman numerals have a base 10 (and 5 half way there) where all the powers of 10 have a symbol.  I for one, X for ten, C for one hundred and M for a thousand and if we need to go further we put lines above X,C,M to get 10000, 100000, and a million then we just make one, two, three of the marks.  We have half ways V for five, L for 50, D for 500 so we don't have to ever make more than four marks. This isn't unnatural or wrong. We don't have to do things the way we do.

Studying the history of math as you say, you could have heard about Old Babylonian math, Plimpton 322 and alike, and the trouble w/o symbol for 0. Comparing this with the a. m. Roman way of counting may give an idea what 10 is in fact.

Sidharth wrote a great answer. I wanted to add on it.
Another way to think about the number 223 is $100 \times 2 + 10\times 2 + 1 \times 3 = 10^2\times2 + 10^1\times2 + 10^0 \times3.$ This is known as working in base 10, where we have a ones digit, a tens digit, a hundreds digit, etc.
We could alternatively work in a different base, and it would be completely equivalent. For example, in base 5, we would write $223_5 = 25\times 2 + 5\times2 + 3\times1 = 5^2\times2 + 5^1\times2 + 5^0\times3 = 63.$
There's no mathematical reason that base 10 is better than other bases, but a likely reason is that we have 10 fingers, so for more humans inventing this number system, it was probably more natural to count in base 10. As Sidharth said, computers count in binary (base 2), and also have hex (base 16). In base 16, you could count all the way up to 16 without needing another digit.

Thanks for pointing out the 10-fingers coincidence! That probably is the actual reason the Hindu-Arabic system even has 10 symbols in the first place.

There is a non mathematical but physical reason why base 2 is preferred by computers (even hex is treated fundamentally like binary in computing). That's due to circuits being able to distinguish ON vs OFF easily than having to dealing with partially ON etc. Just a side comment, doesn't negate anything said in this good answer

Most societies use base 10 since we have 10 fingers (obviously including the thumbs).  So the ones place is how many fingers we're holding up and the tens place is how many times we "flash our hands open".
It's of course possible to use any base if you can come up with enough symbols for a digit.

So this question actually has to do with language even though it seems like a mathematical question.
In English, and most languages that use the indo-arab numerals there are 10 symbols for representing numbers which specifies a mathematical system called the decimal system. These are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. After that we have no further symbols and so we wrap around declaring "10" to be the next number, so on and so forth.
But if we were machines using just 0,1 thus using the binary system then "10" would refer to the number we commonly think of as 2 in our english-decimal system. Notice here "how we write a number in a system" and "what that means" are different things. 10 by itself doesn't mean ANYTHING until you know what system it is in. In fact to confuse you more; we write that we are base-10 system in decimal and the binary folks ALSO Write they are are a base-10 system. Because our 10 is 10. And  their "2" is also 10. But you can skip this riddle for later :)
Likewise if we were using the HEX system (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F) then "A" refers to the number we think of as "10" in decimal english. This is an example of expressing decimal-english 10 as a single digit as you were seeking and is very common in computer science. This is also an example of the "additional unique symbols" that "someone else" you spoke to was referring to.
You can make up any system you like, but because you are speaking English you refer to the concept behind "10" through the word 10.

The names for numbers in your language and the notation you use when writing numbers and calculating with them are really separate issues.  For example, English and French have traces of a base-20 system (cf. "four score" and "quatre-vingts"), but just about everybody uses the base-10 Hindu-Arabic system.

I think I could have written this answer a bit better. There is specifically an interplay between "the philosophical concept of 10 as a number", "the string 10 we use in English due to adoption of the Hindu-Arabic system" and then the fact that "base-10" has a technical meaning in mathematics. And being able to coherently notice and separate these concepts and understand why each one came to be historically would probably give the OP the clarity they are looking for.

In particular the answer, "...because we use a decimal system: because the english language has adoped hindu-arabic numerals to represent the concept you think of as the number ten." then makes sense.

But it's not really the language that adopted the Hindu-Arabic numerals, it's the culture.
